# Connection to database PHP

Tags: database, connection

I have a problem, when i'm trying connect to database, on my webside shows something like that idk why :(

> connect_error) { die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); } echo "Connected successfully"; ?>

```
 <head>
 <?php
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "admin";


  // Create connection
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
  // Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }
  echo "Connected successfully";
 ?>
```

[image]

Comment: I think you must have an extra character in your code so `$conn->connect_error` is somehow being seen by PHP as `$conn-?>connect_error` and the `?>` ends the PHP code block. Try deleting that one line of code, and then carefully type it again.

Comment: nope ;( still the same ;/

Comment: What file extension are you using? .php or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this code to check the connection

```
if (!$conn) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

echo "Connected successfully." . PHP_EOL;
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Comment: when i used this code, the problem was gone, but there is no echo that tells me "connected"

Comment: Ok I edited the answered and added the echo you wanted.

Comment: still nothing, i put connection to footer to see clearly but nothing happend

Comment: It is not visible for some reason. The php is correct. Delete the `exit;` if you want. Try using `?><script>alert('Connected');</script><?php` instead of `echo "Connected successfully." . PHP_EOL;`

Answer (score 0):

This code below should work. It's similar to yours, check up on your database credentials though, as this may lead to some type of error..

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$database = "MyGuests";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Comment: Which PHP version are you using? What software to host the Apache and MySql server are you using?

Comment: i used MySQL Workbench only should i change it ? because i have some problems with xampp

Comment: I haven't ever heard of MySQL Workbench honestly.. but if I had to guess then I'd say it's a problem with the software that for some reason isn't compatible with your PHP code. Then again, you're using mysqli in your code. Try using MySql alone..

Comment: Here is the documentation over it -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php